# Showing that the sequence $\Big(\frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2 ((-\pi, \pi))$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

If we take the inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt$ on $L^2 ((-\pi, \pi))$, which allows functions to $\mathbb{C}$, then it's not hard to check that $\Big(\frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal *sequence* in the space, but I'm having trouble showing it to be an orthonormal basis -- i.e. a complete orthonormal sequence. I tried using the characterisation of complete orthonormal sequences telling us that for any $f \in L^2 ((-\pi, \pi))$, $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f, e_n \rangle|^2 = ||f||^2,$$ where we define $e_n =\frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}},$ but the products on the left were difficult because they're not as easily transformable into ordinary complex line integrals as $\langle e_m, e_n \rangle$ is . Trying to use the definition -- where $\langle f, e_n \rangle = 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\implies f=0$ -- but that presents the same difficulty.

Is there a simple way of proving the completeness of this sequence?

Comment: You only need to prove it for $f$ in a dense subspace of $L^2$. For example, step functions, or continuous functions.

Comment: OK, that sounds quite difficult too. But if that's the simplest approach, I guess there's just not one of those very neat solutions.

Comment: Have you had a course in Complex Variables?

Comment: Is $L^2((-\pi, \pi))$ the same as $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$? The answers seem all assume they're same.

Answer (score 7):

One of the more interesting proofs of completeness uses complex analysis. Consider the expression
$$
             F(\lambda) = \frac{i}{1-e^{-2\pi i\lambda}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-i\lambda t}g(t)dt.
$$
The function $F(\lambda)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, with possible first order poles at $\lambda=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$. The residue at $\lambda = n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the Fourier coefficient,
$$
     \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow n}(\lambda-n)F(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-int}g(t)dt.
$$
Suppose $g\in L^2[0,2\pi]$ is orthogonal to $e^{int}$ for all $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$. Then $F(\lambda)$ extends to an entire function of $\lambda$. It can be shown that $F$ is uniformly bounded on squares centered at the origin of width $1,3,5,7,\cdots$. Revisiting the proof of Liouville's Theorem, it is not hard to conclude that $F$ is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{C}$ and, hence, must be constant (and the constant must be $0$.) Hence, $F\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{C}$. From that one obtains $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-i\lambda t}g(t)dt=0$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, which leads to the conclusion that all derivatives are $0$ and, hence, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}t^n g(t)dt=0$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. Because the polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,2\pi]$, it follows that $g=0$ a.e.. Therefore, the orthogonal complement of the span of $\{ e^{int} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ is $\{ 0 \}$, which proves that $\{ e^{int}/\sqrt{2\pi} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll look at it carefully and see if I understand properly before accepting.

Comment: I don't think I follow this thing about $F$ being uniformly bounded on squares centered at the origin with the widths being as you stated.  That being said, if this proof is correct, it looks like it can be applied to show that $\{e^{i \lambda_n t}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is complete in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ for much more general sequences than just $\lambda_n = n$.

Comment: @Dan1618 : There are several requirements to make a more general argument work. First, you need a holomorphic function that has first order zeroes at all $\lambda_n$. I'm not sure how to get that for the cases you are suggesting.

Comment: It works for any shift of the integers. E.g something like $\lambda_n = n+1/2$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The proof above doesn't apply because we lose the algebra property that $\{e^{int}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ satisfy. Let me know if I'm wrong here as this is something I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

It *isn't* a basis - you need to let $n$ range over $\mathbb Z$. Specifcally, if $e_n(t)=\frac{e^{int}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, then $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is a basis of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. The easiest way to prove this is to use Stone-Weierstrass.

Let $X:=\{f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb R: f\text{ is continuous, }f(-\pi)=f(\pi)\}$. Observe that we can identify $X$ with the set of continuous functions on the torus $\mathbb T$, which is a compact metric space. Now if we define $\mathcal A=\operatorname{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$, $\mathcal A$ is a sub-algebra of $X$; it is clearly a subspace and it is closed under multiplication since $e_ne_m=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e_{n+m}$. We apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to deduce that $\mathcal A$ is dense in $X$ (in the uniform topology). There are three conditions we need to check:

1. $\mathcal A$ is unital. This is clear since $\sqrt{2\pi}e_0=1$.
2. $\mathcal A$ is closed under conjugation. Observe that $\overline{e_n(t)}=e_{-n}(t)$, so this follows too.
3. $\mathcal A$ separates points. If $s,t\in(-\pi,\pi]$ with $s\neq t$ then either $\cos s\neq\cos t$ or $\sin s\neq \sin t$, so in particular $e_1(s)\neq e_1(t)$.

Hence the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applies: for every $f\in X$, there exists a sequence $\{f_k\}$ in $\mathcal A$ suchb that $f_k\to f$ uniformly. This implies $f_k\to f$ in $L^2$, and hence $\mathcal A$ is $L^2$-dense in $X$. Since $X$ is $L^2$-dense in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, the proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've never heard of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem -- I was wondering more if an elementary proof existed, but I get the feeling it doesn't.

Comment: [Stone-Weierstrass theorem (complelx version) in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem#Stone–Weierstrass_theorem%2C_complex_version) uses $C(X, \mathbb{C})$(complex locally continued functions) as function space rather than $L^2$ functions. Stone-Weierstrass theorem can also apply on $L^2$ functions?

Comment: Uniform convergence implies $L^2$-convergence, as I mention in the last paragraph.

Comment: Any idea how we could change this proof to say that $\{e^{i(n+1/2)}t\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} $ is an orthonormal basis? Orthogonality is obvious, but completeness I'm not sure about. We no longer have that the algebra property.

Comment: @Dan1618 Let $g(t)=e^{it/2}$. If $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, then so is $f/g$ and so there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $f/g = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_ne_n$. But this implies $f=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_nge_n$, showing that the orthonormal sequence $\{ge_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is complete.

Comment: @Jason Yes, of course. I embarrassingly figured that out that same proof a few days ago.

Comment: how you prove the set A is dense in L2(-pi,pi) where A={f: f:[-pi,pi]--C and f(-pi)=f(pi)}..plz tell me i did not get this